# How we fire 2 or more events continuously in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, navigation

I'm facing a below problem when redirect to view the detail page then wanna display Edit popup.

Please help me resolve this.

In my component js.

```
    var retParams = '0010k000008IsVXXX' // Id of object
    var naviSObject= $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    naviSObject.setParams({
        "recordId": retParams,
        "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
    naviSObject.fire();

    var editRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:editRecord');
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        'recordId': retParams
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
```

The first event **naviSObject** is firing, but **editRecordEvent** is not working. 
Salesforce Lightning has other component or event which can support my case. 
Please indicate to me.

P/s: I have tried the settimeout for the second event and The both events are working perfectly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because it is navigating away from the page before the edit event can fire.  I'm assuming that you want to open the record you are redirecting to in an 'Edit' state.

Try this:

Add to you html file

```
 <lightning:navigation aura:id="navigationService" />
```

Then, where you are wanting to do the navigating, try this:

```
cmp.find("navigationService").navigate({
   "type": "standard__recordPage",
   "attributes": {
       "recordId": retParams,
       "objectApiName": "<yourObjectHere>",
       "actionName": "edit"
   }
});
```

Link reference [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Your solution is great! It's working for my case.